# Looping back by one C++

Tags: c++

at the moment i'm writing C++ small console game and I have a problem. Essence of the problem is that I can't return loop back by one.

Here's My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    Main:
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        vector <string> v;
        vector <char> v1;
        string word;
        cin >> word;
        char lastChar = word.at(word.length() - 1);
        cout << "Word's last character is:" << lastChar << endl;
        char firstChar1 = word[0];
        //v.push_back(word);
        if (i == 1) {
            v1.push_back(lastChar);
            v1.push_back(firstChar1);
        }
        string word1;
        cin >> word1;
        char firstChar = word1[0];
        cout << "Word's first character is:" << firstChar << endl;
        if (i==1) v1.push_back(firstChar);
        char lastChar1 = word1.at(word1.length() - 1);
        v1.push_back(lastChar1);
        //Checking:
            if (lastChar != firstChar) {
                cout << "Game stopped" << endl;
                //cout << "Your score is " << wordcounter << endl;
                break;
    }
}
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I want that user must input the word that begins with the last letter of the previous word, for example "deer". Then again, a word that begins with "r" letter, etc. And my code works only for two words. When i have inputted third word,It started the loop again and didn't look at the previous word.

Current Output:

```
deer

Word's last character is:r

rabbit

Word's first character is:r

Ball

Word's last character is:l
```

when i will input the ball,the working code will write that Game Stopped. But my code is wrong,unfortunately.

Please Help,

Thanks.

Comment: Someone's about to tell you `goto` read a good programming book before you use that keyword...

Comment: By the way, those lines under `goto Main` - when exactly were you hoping to have them executed?

Comment: Oh,I posted the old code. I have to edit it.

Comment: Don't post it just yet. Take your time to design it properly first.

Comment: Thanks,but i'm new at the stackoverflow. I tried many experiments,etc. and also Goto. but I cannot solve it.

Comment: One fundamental example is that everything above the `else` should go into a separate function which will `return lastChar != firstChar`.

Comment: @GùrìCôppérfîéld can you add what the current output is?

Comment: Of course you can go back by one in the loop just type `i--`

Comment: You don't seem to have a problem with looping, but rather with the algorithm.

Comment: Yes,I think the problem is also algorithm. but also i cannot solve this.:( I have tried many of algorithms,also except algorithms I tried Goto and Functions.

Comment: Stop talking about goto!  You've not used it, and you're not going to use it!

Answer (score 0):

if `if(lastChar != firstChar)` fails, then it should set `lastChar` to the `word1` lastChar and check it in next iteration. Edited code is here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector> 
using namespace std; 
int main() {
char lastChar;
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    vector <string> v;
    vector <char> v1;
    string word;
    cin >> word;
    char firstChar1 = word[0];
    if (i >= 1){                //check in 2nd iteraion and so on iteration.
        if (lastChar != firstChar1)
            break;
    }
    lastChar = word.at(word.length() - 1);
    cout << "Word's last character is:" << lastChar << endl;

    //v.push_back(word);
    if (i == 1) {
        v1.push_back(lastChar);
        v1.push_back(firstChar1);
    }
    string word1;
    cin >> word1;
    char firstChar = word1[0];
    cout << "Word's first character is:" << firstChar << endl;
    if (i == 1) v1.push_back(firstChar);
    char lastChar1 = word1.at(word1.length() - 1);
    v1.push_back(lastChar1);
    //Checking:
    if (lastChar != firstChar) {
        break;
    }
       lastChar = word1.at(word1.length() - 1);    //new line added.
}
cout << "Game stopped" << endl;
//cout << "Your score is " << wordcounter << endl;
return 0;
```

}